# How to do communication between components

Tags: angular, events

As per below image, say I've got two `@Component`(s):

- `MenuComponent`
- `TableComponent`
  [image]

Both are `ContainerComponent` children.

`MenuComponent` fires an event (via `EventEmitter`) to "say" we want all the table rows selected. This event is catched at the `ContainerComponent` level.

What's the better strategy to let `TableComponent` know that it has to select all the rows of its table?

I could use the `@ViewChild` strategy, but I don't like direct components access. Any other idea?

Comment: You may want to consider making it at least three (3) components. Another component wrapping the menu + table that can filter/sort/map data. Listening for events either through @Output or through a shared service.The child components could become more "dumb", simply taking in data and emitting events. For something like "select all", the parent/container component can use something like `map()` to update a "selected" property for each "row" in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple

```html
<app-container>
  <app-menu #menu (selectAllRows)="table.selectAllRows($event)">

  </app-menu>
  <app-table #table>

  </app-table>
</app-container>
```

Comment: That's basically equal to using `@ViewChild`, but the handling is delegated to the template. Do you think this is the only solution?

Comment: Yeah but you're not using `@ViewChild`. And there's plethora of solutions (services, view children, injectors - if you're severely debilitated -, ...), most are [explained here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). But this one is hands down the easiest to implement, read, and use (according to myself).

Comment: Thanks! I really don't need to have a service or to use injection to do this. It would be all boilerplate.

Comment: Well a service can be useful (again, that's my two cents) since it allows to easily share common behaviors. So if you have to write this once, use the code I provided, but if you have several instances of arrays that can have all of their rows selected, consider using either a service or a custom component with greater  abstraction